# Script to change terminal shortcut to open in fullscreen

Tags: scripts

I want a script that automates creating a launcher so it runs `gnome-terminal --window --full-screen` and adding it to the Unity Launcher Something that could be run right after system setup for initial system configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2017-05-01:**

The OP changed the wording of the question. To better address his concerns, I am making an addition to the top of my post and leaving the original answer below.

Here is a script to automate the process of creating a launcher on the Unity Launcher to open a full-screen session of gnome-terminal. It must be run as the user for whom the launcher should be added. I cannot be run with sudo!

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# This script automates the process of creating a desktop launcher to open a 
# full-screen terminal and then adds that launcher to the Unity Launcher

# Change this path if you want to drop the desktop launcher somewhere else
# Note that the user must have full permissions on the path
launcherPath="$HOME/fst.desktop"

# This is the launcher file
launcher="#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=gnome-terminal --window --full-screen
Name=Full Window Terminal
Comment=comment here
Icon=gnome-terminal"

# Save the launcher and make it executable
echo "$launcher" > "$launcherPath"
chmod +x "$launcherPath"

# Default Unity Launcher favorites
#    ['application://ubiquity.desktop', \
#   'application://org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', \
#   'application://firefox.desktop', \
#   'application://libreoffice-writer.desktop', \
#   'application://libreoffice-calc.desktop', \
#   'application://libreoffice-impress.desktop', \
#   'application://org.gnome.Software.desktop', \
#   'application://ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop', \
#   'application://unity-control-center.desktop', \
#   'unity://running-apps', \
#   'unity://expo-icon', \
#   'unity://devices']

# You can add or remove items from this list as you see fit. For example, 
# removing the line for `*ubuntu-amazon*` will remove the amazon launcher
favorites="['application://ubiquity.desktop', \
'application://org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', \
'application://firefox.desktop', \
'application://libreoffice-writer.desktop', \
'application://libreoffice-calc.desktop', \
'application://libreoffice-impress.desktop', \
'application://org.gnome.Software.desktop', \
'application://ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop', \
'application://unity-control-center.desktop', \
'unity://running-apps', \
'application://$launcherPath', \
'unity://expo-icon', \
'unity://devices']"

gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "$favorites"
```

Once this script is saved in a file and made executable, running it with a regular user account will drop the launcher on the Unity Launcher.

---

**Launcher that can be pinned to Unity Launcher**

If you want a launcher that you can pin, create a file named something `.desktop` like `full-screen-terminal.desktop` with the following contents...

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=gnome-terminal --window --full-screen
Name=Full Window Terminal
Comment=comment here
Icon=gnome-terminal
```

Save this file and make it executable. Double-click it to run. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch apps so you can see the Unity Launcher. Now you can pin the running full-screen terminal "app" in the Unity Launcher.

Comment: Ok but I'm asking for a script. It is to add it to my configuration script so it should be something like `cat << EOF > file_name   file_text EOF` and it should automatically remove the previous shortcut in the panel.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. Do you mean that you want a script that automates creating the launcher I described above and adding it to the Unity Launcher? Something that could be run right after system setup for initial system configuration?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I'll edit the question so it's more clear.

Comment: This can be pretty easily accomplished, by making your script write the launcher contents above to a file, mark it executable, and then using the `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "launcher-contents-string"`. Use `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites` to get the current list of launcher contents for modification. It's late where I am.  If you need more help with this. Let me know, and I'll check back in the morning.

Comment: I'll edit your answer with what I've done. It isn't working because I don't know where to save the desktop file.

Comment: @Arturo I rejected your edit because the script you added is fundamentally different from b_laoshi's answer. Please add your own answer.